# C++ D&D Point Buy - Point Tracking?

Tags: c++

I'm teaching myself C++ by coding a D&D 5E character creator.  I'm aware that it will be at least a three-step process, where I (1) learn the language, (2) implement data validation, then (3) learn and implement proper conventions.

I'm trying to only use standard libraries.  Right now I'm working on the ability score point buy system.  It might be that I'm exhausted, but I'm not sure how to properly track point expenditure.

See, in the point buy system, you can allocate 27 points among your six ability scores.  They each start at 8.  It costs one point per increase, up to 13, then two points per increase, up to 15.  Values above 15 and below 8 are impermissible.

I've gotten points to be tracked, and the upper and lower bounds recognized. I just can't figure any way (let alone a simple and elegant one like I'd prefer) to adjust the point costs for scores entering or leaving 14 or 15.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string abilities[6] = { "STR", "DEX", "CON", "INT", "WIS", "DEX" };

    bool editing = 1;

    int stats[6] = { 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 };
    int points = 27;

    while (editing == 1)
    {
        int select = 0;
        int adjust = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int remainder = 0;

        cout << "You have " << points << " points to spend on your ability scores." << endl;
        cout << "Select a number to adjust that ability's score:\n1) STR = " << stats[0] << "\n2) DEX = " << stats[1] << "\n3) CON = " << stats[2] << "\n4) INT = " << stats[3] << "\n5) WIS = " << stats[4] << "\n6) CHA = " << stats[5] << endl;
        cout << "Select a number outside the above range to finalize your ability scores.\n";
        cin >> select;

        while (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid entry; try again: ";
            cin >> select;
        }

        select -= 1;

        if (select < 0 || select > 5)
        {
            editing = 0;
            break;
        }

        cout << "Adjust " << stats[select] << " " << abilities[select] << " by how much? ";
        cin >> adjust;

        result = (stats[select] + adjust);

        if (result < 8)
        {
            cout << "Ability scores cannot be lower than 8 in the point buy system.\n";
        }
        else if (result > 15)
        {
            cout << "Ability scores cannot be higher than 15 in the point buy system.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            remainder = stats[select] - result;
            points += remainder;
            if (points < 1)
            {
                cout << "You do not have the points for that operation.";
                break;
            }
            else if (points > 27)
            {
                cout << "You cannot accrue more than 27 points.";
                break;
            }
            stats[select] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples I could tear apart?

EDIT:

...replace the 4th to last line in the code above to enact a tedious and inelegant solution to my query:

```
            if (stats[select] == 15 && result == 14)
            {
                points += remainder + 1;
            }
            else if (stats[select] == 15 && result < 14)
            {
                points += remainder + 2;
            }
            else if (stats[select] == 14 && result < 14)
            {
                points += remainder + 1;
            }
            else if (result == 15 && stats[select] == 14)
            {
                points += remainder - 1;
            }
            else if (result == 15 && stats[select] < 14)
            {
                points += remainder - 2;
            }
            else if (result == 14 && stats[select] < 14)
            {
                points += remainder - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                points += remainder;
            }
            stats[select] = result;
```

This still isn't perfect; the extra points for the conditionals are independent from the check to see if there are enough points left to perform the operation.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to refine any of the other code present are welcome.  Just remember that I started coding yesterday, so my ability to grasp your suggestions may be limited.

Comment: **Try something simpler.** Try writing a program with no user input, with a function that takes a score and a number of points, and increases the score by one and decrements the points accordingly (if there are enough points). The `main()` can call that a few times with diffrent arguments, and print the results. Get this working perfectly before you attempt anything more complex.

Comment: @Beta, your advice brought me to learn random number generation, but it did not answer my question.

Comment: I did not find the solution I was looking for, but I made the code workable by entering a series of `if else` statements to add/subtract one/two from the point totals in the events that the original value and/or the result was a 14 or 15.

Comment: I can't answer this because it is closed but look at https://onlinegdb.com/HJWbojwmL for one that uses arrays and https://onlinegdb.com/S1ggzjiDXL for one that uses a map. Basically what you want is an array of how many points each level requires.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: Thank you!  My code is soo rudimentary, so I appreciate being pointed in the direction of new concepts like arrays (which I have a passing familiarity with) and maps (which I've never heard of before)!

Comment: @SorrieCharly  If arrays are too new then then answer below is good - it just uses a switch inside a function to simulate an array (or you could even use a bunch of if statements inside a function and it would still act like an array)

Comment: @SorrieCharly The only real differences between a map and an array are 1) the elements in the map are always sorted so finding an item is faster compared to looping through looking at every element in an array and 2) you can use anything as the index for a map but an array requires an integer index.  So in my map example I use the ability name as the index and in my array example I use the number from the menu (just like you did)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing arithmetic with the adjustment, why not just have a lookup of stat to points cost?

```
// outside main()
int stat_cost(int stat) {
    switch (stat){
        case 8: return 0;
        case 9: return 1;
        case 10: return 2;
        case 11: return 3;
        case 12: return 4;
        case 13: return 5;
        case 14: return 7;
        case 15: return 9;
        default: throw std::out_of_range("stat must be between 8 and 15 (inclusive)");
    }
}

// after checking result is in range
int points_result = points - stat_cost(result) + stat_cost(stats[select]);
if (points_result < 0)
{
    std::cout << "You do not have the points for that operation.";
    break;
}
else if (points_result > 27) // N.b. This condition can never be true
{
    std::cout << "You cannot accrue more than 27 points.";
    break;
}
points = points_result;
stats[select] = result;
```

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but I'll have to digest it to fully understand the switching and `out_of_range`.  This is just the sort of elegant solution I was looking for!